# Appending results of function into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to append the results of this function  into list

```
import time
def function1(x,y,z):
    while True :
    x= 0
    y=0
    z=0
    print (str(x).zfill(2)+ ":" +str(y).zfill(2)+ ":" +str(z).zfill(2))
    z=z+1
    time.sleep(1)
    if z == 60 :
       z = 0
       y = y + 1
    if y== 50 and z== 1:
       return
```

I want that list will be something like that

```
my_list=['00:00:00','00:00:01','00:00:02',...,'00:50:00']
```

Is something like that possible !
Thaanks in advance

Comment: indent you code properly please. What is inside the `while` block?

Comment: also why do you want to wait 50 min to get that list?

Comment: Please provide more info. what are you returning at the end? why dont you have break for this while loop? And please indent your code

Comment: i used `while True` in order to loop forever

Comment: @HANAAYK: you also have a `return` statement. I can't tell if that's inside the loop, but either the loop loops forever and that statement is never reached, or the loop ends when the function returns.

Comment: Anyway a function that loops forever has no results to append to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit. First of all, you don't need any arguments when you define your function as you set `x=y=z=0` in your code. Also, you need to take that outside of your loop, or it will run forever. Next, you can make an empty list before looping, and then append what you want.

```
import time
def function1():
    my_list = []
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0
    while True :
        t = str(x).zfill(2)+ ":" +str(y).zfill(2)+ ":" +str(z).zfill(2)
        my_list.append(t)
        print(t)
        z += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if z == 60:
            z = 0
            y += 1
        if y== 50 and z== 1:
            return my_list
```

Then you can return `my_list` at the end of you loop